# Add multiple values to Json String

Tags: python, json

I have a For loop that extracts objects from your database query. Now I'm looking for a way to add these objects to an existing JSON string.

My list looks like this:

```
i = [(2, 23322323, 'object1name', 'example1'),(3, 2323232, 'object2name', 'example2'),(4, 12312312, 'object3name','example3')]
```

My For loop looks like this:

```
count = 1
for item in i:
    object = item[2], item[3]
    print("Object",count, item[2], item[3])
    count = count + 1
```

My JSON String looks like this:

```
payload = json.dumps({'intent': 'test', 'message': message, 'url':imageURL})
```

I would like to have the following JSON output:

```
payload = json.dumps({'intent': 'test', 'message': message, 'url':imageURL, 'objetc1':object1, 'object2': object2})
```

I have tried to add the objects with:

```
payload['object'] = item[2], item[3]
```

But unfortunately I don't know how to add all objects and additionally the ascending numbering so Object1, Object2 and so on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please add your object structure for help.

Comment: I add a sample datastructure

Comment: My answer as per below. Please use my method to convert payload from string to dictionary to add elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since json has dumped the value into payload, note **payload** is of type **string**. Need to convert **payload** to type **dictionary** to add elements.

```
# Loads payload back to dictionary
p = json.loads(payload)

# Add objects accordingly as per below
for index, item in enumerate(i):
    p['object' + str(index)] = item[2], item[3]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. How can I remove the brackets from the items in the JSON string?

Comment: Sounds good! That item[2], item[3] belongs together as mentioned in your code. Those are grouped together as type of "tuple". If you want to separate it, I suggest you can alter my code to be p['object' + str(index)]  = item[2] and next line will be p['example' + str(index)]  = item[3]

Comment: Ok perfect, now I have understand it. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you do not need to keep track of the count. This is because python has a useful `enumerate` function which returns both the item in the list and its position. So instead, you can do something like this:

```py
fruits=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango']
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    print(i, fruit)
```

This will give an output like:

```
0 Apple
1 Banana
2 Mango
```

So now that you have the count, you can use the count to keep track of the object count in your json key.

```py
fruits=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango']
d={}
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    d['fruit'+str(i)]=fruit
d
```

This is going to give an output like:

```
{'fruit0': 'Apple', 'fruit1': 'Banana', 'fruit2': 'Mango'}
```

Just replace fruits with the items in your database and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your object structure but i think this will help you.

```
a={'intent': 'test', 'message': 'message', 'url':'imageURL'}
i=["ssdds","rajkot","baroda"]
count = 1
for item in range(len(i)):
  a["object"+str(item+1)]=i[item]
print(a)
```

Comment: I add a sample datastructure

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(i):
    payload['object' + str(index)] = item
```